# Databricks notebook workflows - Log Entries from Child notebook not recorded in Azure App

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks

I have implemented a small Databricks Notebook workflow where a parent notebook invokes another notebook. I  also have a shared notebook, which is included in both notebooks. In this shared notebook I have a function to get a logger instance like this:

```
def initializeLogging(first_time):

  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

  if  not first_time:
    # Set the log level
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # TODO: Load the instrumentation key from the Key Vault
    instrumentation_key = '<key here>'

    # Add our Handler for Azure Monitor
    logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(connection_string=f'InstrumentationKey={instrumentation_key}'))
    
  return logger
```

In the parent notebook I call `initializeLogging(True)`, and in the child notebook I call it with false (`initializeLogging(False)`, since I don't want to re-initialize the logger

I can see the Parent log entries is Application Insights, but I can never see the child notebook's log entry, and I am not sure why.

I have tried passing True to my initializeLogging method from the child notebook, with the same result (no App Insights log entries on the child notebook).

Has anybody tried this before?

Comment: how do you invoke child notebooks?

Comment: I use dbutils.notebook.run()